# Where I can host my proprietary Maven artifacts?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

What are my options to host proprietary (non open-source) Maven artifacts online?

Answer (score 2):

I like Nexus.  sonatype.org or sonatype.com depending on whether you want the open source repository or commercial.